# Define a void f(void) function but with variables from the same scope?

Tags: c++

Considering this piece of code

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   string a = "hello world";
   void (*f) = []() {
      cout << a << endl;
   }
}
```

How can I define `f` such that the type of `f` is `void (*f)(void)`? Without using `[&]`.

The motive is that I want to store in a struct this function `f`, but I don't want to give the struct `a`.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Why not simply define `void f()`? A regular function. Why involve lambdas at all?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yes @Jesper Juhl, I can't define `void f()` inside `main` and I need variables declares in `main`.

Comment: @truvaking obviously you can define a function outside main. If not, you are working within unreasonable constraints.

Comment: By the way, capturing a variable by reference is unsafe if the lambda outlives original variable. You’ll want to capture by value (`=`)

Comment: @JesperJuhl no it has to be INSIDE main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is only convertible to a function pointer if it does not capture anything (because captures amount to dynamic memory allocation, and would require destruction/deallocation later, which a function pointer type does not offer).

[`ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator_ret.28.2A.29.28params.29.28.29)
:

> This user-defined conversion function is only defined if the capture list of the lambda-expression is empty.

If you want to store a *capturing* lambda in a struct, you can store it as a [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: tl;dr **you can't**

Comment: The `std::function` method works fine for my needs!